# Drive API : Permissions 403 Rate Limit exceeded

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

We try to integrate Drive API (Java) in our app and we wanted to be able to manage Drive's permissions. Unfortunatly, we reach the 403 Rate Limit and permissions aren't change afterward.

I already did some research and I found a lot of times the answer : there is **a limit of 50/day** for this kind of things. I can't really fully explain what we do, but we have hundreds of users who could use it every day. So this is too short for what we have to do. And I can't find a way to possibly extend it.

Did I miss or misunderstood something? It seems odd to me to have such a low limit a day, if someone can explain it to me I will be grateful.

PS : I found also some explanations on batch/ExponentialBackoff but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: There are two types of rate limit errors.  Normal "rate Limit" which is project based and related to what your project and all its users are doing as a whole.  "User Rate Limit Exceeded" are user limits and based upon what a single user is doing.  I would expect a permissions rate limit to throw a User Rate Limit as it should be based upon what a single user is doing.   I would do some testing if i where you to see what really causes this error.

Comment: "403 Rate Limit" is normally related to flood protection and your app is going to fast.  Make sure you add quotaUser on all your requests if you have more then one user from a single ip address.  Users are default denoted by the ip address unless you send quotauser

Comment: I see, I will try to have a more specific error and I will reply here again. Thanks

Comment: if you are using the google apis java client library it should have ExponentialBackoff  implemented you shouldn't have to do anything